# Bases of a point set topology

Tags: general-topology

Below is an excerpt from Loring's 'An Introduction to Manifolds" where he says verbatim, "A collection $\mathcal{B}$ of subsets of a set $S$ is a basis for some topology $\mathcal{T}$ on $S$ if and only if..." [image]

I need some clarification with the proof going backwards. The author first defines $\mathcal{T}$ to be the collection of all sets that are unions of sets in $\mathcal{B}$. He then claims that this means $\emptyset, S\in\mathcal{T}$. Why is this true? In this part of the proof, all we know is that $\mathcal{B}$ is a collection of subsets of $S$. If $S = {1, 2, 3, 4}$ then we can let $\mathcal{B} = \{ \{1\}, \{1, 2\} \}$. Clearly, $\mathcal{B}$ is a collection of subsets of $S$. Then the collection of all sets that are unions of sets in $\mathcal{B}$ clearly does not have $\emptyset$ nor $S$.

Moving along, why does this construction of $\mathcal{T}$ have anything to do with the proof? $\mathcal{T}$ is a collection of union of sets of $\mathcal{B}$ while point (i) is interested in the union of every set in $\mathcal{B}$.

Comment: Every open set must be representable as the union of sets in the basis. Since the empty set and $S$ are open they must be the union of some elements in the basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In this part of the proof, all we know is that $\mathcal{B}$ is a collection of subsets of $S$.

No, you know that $\mathcal{B}$ is a collection of subsets of $S$ which satisfies $(1)$ and $(2)$. The fact that $\emptyset \in \tau$ is true because you can consider the empty union, while $S \in \tau$ is condition $(1)$. Note that the example you make does not satisfy condition $(1)$ of the proposition.

> Moving along, why does this construction of $\mathcal{T}$ have anything to do with the proof? $\mathcal{T}$ is a collection of union of sets of $\mathcal{B}$ while point (i) is interested in the union of every set in $\mathcal{B}$.

What you show is that $\tau$ is a topology on $S$ and $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis for this topology, $\tau$ consists of all the subsets of $S$ which can be written as a union of elements of $\mathcal{B}$.

Comment: Could you clarify how you know $\emptyset\in\mathcal{T}$?

Comment: When the book says "define $\tau$ as the collection of sets...", just take the empty union (i.e. take no set of $\mathcal{B}$) . If you prefer, you can directly define $\tau$ as the collection of sets which are unions of sets of $\mathcal{B}$ plus the empty set. Then the proof is exactly the same.

Comment: Oh I see, basically take the vacuous statement that the Union of nothing is the empty set. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, that's right!